# Sidebar menu Navigation hiding for user based login

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the login specific side bar menu for the users on my html page, like for admin users their should be 4 to five sidebar menu but for users there will be only one static menu, i wrote a jquery to hide the side bar, but it didn't work can you guys`

> 

```
<aside class="main-sidebar"> 
>         <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
>         <section class="sidebar">
>             <ul class="sidebar-menu">
>                  <li class="active treeview"> <p hidden id="munHome"> <a href="home.html"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
> <span>Home</span></a></p></li>
>                 <li class="treeview"> <a href="chart.html"> <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i> <span>Graphs</span> </a></li>
>                 <li class="treeview">  <p hidden id="munViewController">  <a href="view-controller.html"> <i class="fa
> fa-eye"></i> <span>View Controllers</span></a></p></li>
>                 <li class="treeview">  <p hidden id="munViewUser"><a href="view-users.html"> <i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>View
> Users</span></a></p></li>
>             </ul>
>         </section>
>         <!-- /.sidebar -->
>     </aside>
```

help me? attached is the jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    if(sessionStorage.getItem("sUserName")){
        var userName=sessionStorage.getItem("sUserName");
        var sUserType=sessionStorage.getItem("sUserType");
        if(sUserType=="2" || sUserType=="1")
        {
             $( "#munHome" ).show();
             $( "#munViewController" ).show();
             $( "#munViewUser" ).show();
            //document.getElementById('btnAddUser').style.visibility = 'visible';
             addUserViaAjax();
        }
        $("#displayUserName").text(userName);
    }
    else{
            window.location.href = "./";
    }
});
```

Comment: which programming language you are using? .Net, PHP or any other ?

Comment: @PHPExpert i'm using JAVA as a language and Spring framework